# Turn an excel sheet to a webpage

Tags: website, microsoft-excel, wix.com

I have an Excel sheet that we use to calculate sales commissions. We, sometimes, share the file with individuals that we prefer they don't see the formulas. One thought came to mind is to convert the Excel file to a webpage as a way to make it *easier* to share with people form outside the organization and also to protect the calculations that we do in the background by hiding the formulas. What methods or apps are there to help in achieving that, our website is on wix business.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to [sheet.new](https://sheet.new) (Google Sheets).
2. Create a Google Account if you haven't already.
3. Go to `File`, then `Import`, then `Upload`, and upload your file.
4. Choose to `Replace` the file (which is empty as you just created it) and validate by pressing `Import data`.
5. You can finally select `File` then `Publish to the web`, and choose the options most relevant to you. (the options are very rich)

I hope that will help!

Comment: Not all the Excel features are supported by Google Sheets, by the other hand publishing to the web makes the data public.